# Java memory leak. JProfiler

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jprofiler

I have a problem with Java memory leak. I wrote a program which works with database and HttpServer. When I was testing it I detected a huge memory leak. When I switch on Jprofiler and found the objects that are causing that. It's a huge amount of Strings with different texts in it. I didn't write all these Strings. I only use JDBC connector

```
import com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
```

[JProfiler Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWKGU.png)

Also there are Strings that contains information about another stuff that I use.
JSON `import org.json.JSONObject;`

My question is: Where all this Strings came from and why they exist at all. They repeats sometimes. They cause a huge memory leak ~700MB for now. I will provide any information that you will need to answer. Thank you!

Comment: those all look like constant strings in your screen shot.  the obvious question regarding using a database, of course, is are you closing all your resources (Statements, ResultSets, Connections, etc)?

Comment: jtahlborn, I don`t close them. Because I thought that GC will do all this stuff. I Use try with resourses for statements

Comment: Maybe using the "merged incoming references" mode will tell you more than looking at single instances.

Comment: Does the amount of used memory increase over time or stays it around the same amount? The strings that are shown in the picture are mostly static string (like translations for some message codes) that would by loaded during startup of the application and then stay in memory during the whole lifetime (but no new strings of this sort are added over the lifetime)

Comment: Thomas Kläger, Why this strings are loaded in the runtime? What are they purpose? Yes, ammount of memory consume increase every time when I do call to the server.It responde and close connection, but doesn`t give up memory, even after GC runned